# How to save index of PageView?

Tags: flutter

I have a PageView to show 4 pages and a BottomNavigationBar to switch them. I'm having troubles with the PageController.

In any page, I navigate to a new Screen, but when get back, the PageView return to the initial page and no to the last page.

Here is how I using the PageView

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _page = 0;
  _pageController = PageController(keepPage: true);
}

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
      title: getAppBarTitle(_page),
      centerTitle: true,
      actions: renderActions(_page)),
  body: PageView(
      children: <Widget>[
        DashboardScreen(),
        InstructionsScreen(),
        CatalogScreen(),
        ProfileScreen()
      ],
      controller: _pageController,
      onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()),
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    key: bottomNavigationBar,
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
    onTap: navigationTapped,
    currentIndex: _page,
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.grey),
          activeIcon:
              Icon(Icons.home, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
          title: Text('Dashboard',
              style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor)),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.receipt, color: Colors.grey),
          activeIcon:
              Icon(Icons.receipt, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
          title: Text('Instructions',
              style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor)),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.dashboard, color: Colors.grey),
          activeIcon:
              Icon(Icons.dashboard, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
          title: Text('Catalog',
              style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor)),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.grey),
          activeIcon:
              Icon(Icons.person, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
          title: Text('Profile',
              style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor)),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white)
    ],
  ),
);

void navigationTapped(int page) {
  _pageController.animateToPage(page,
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.ease);
}

void onPageChanged(int page) {
  setState(() {
    this._page = page;
  });
}
```

In the DashboardScreen for example, I go to a new page like:

```
Navigator.of(context)
            .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CodeScreen()))
```

How can I fix this? I need to use Redux or Bloc to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: I Tried your Code, work as Expected - i Pushed to new Screen & then pop Back to same Page as Expected & not to _page = 0 .

Comment: Here is a gif of how is working now https://imgur.com/a/nr2VqtY is weird that the pageview is not retaining the index.

Comment: Could you show us how you are closing your CodeScreen?

Comment: I'm using the Navigator.pop() and the back button in the AppBar to go back.